# Is logical address generated by CPU and MMU same if Physical and Virtual address space are same?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management

The system has same physical and virtual address space i.e. 32-bit. Are the logical address generated by CPU and address generated by MMU same?

Comment: What are you calling “logical address” and what's the difference with a virtual address?

Comment: Beware that every process has its own address space, free to use, so virtual addresses may overlap, while the physical addresses may not.

Answer (score 0):

It can be but not necessarily.

The MMU can be setup to translate adresses. There is nothing stopping you from having swapping physical adresses between, say, two logical segments and still have the same amount of logical and physical adresses. Sounds a bit unusual to me, but not impossible.

Comment: On systems with 64 bit pointers, the logical  address space is often laid out so that casting a 32 bit integer to a pointer can never produce a valid address. So -2GB to +4GB would not be available. Catches lots of bugs. So on a system with 16GB of non virtual memory, logical address space could reasonably be 4GB to 20GB.